# Android how to implement executing Async task from runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

The documentation says that execute() must be called from a UI thread. But, since I am updating images every few seconds, I am using a Runnable. And in that, I define the operations that have to be executed. Starting(execute())ASyncTask is one of them. But, since ASyncTask is not supposed to be called from anything but the UI thread, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add  [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in Runnable for starting  AsyncTask :

```
private Runnable updateImages= new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                // call your asynctask here 
            }
        }
    });
    //////YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: You almost have to put that runOnUiThread in a conditional, or it will slow down your entire program

Comment: Can I do a sendMessage instead of runOnUiThread and then since the Handler's implemented on the UI thread, I will handle the message i.e. start the ASyncTask there.

Comment: @Namratha : `runOnUiThread` also implemented on the UI thread. `runOnUiThread` is method of Activity class not from any thread. i suggest `runOnUiThread` because it's easy to implement.

Comment: @Namratha : if you have any issue in implementing   `runOnUiThread` or Updating UI from `runOnUiThread` then tell me i will try to help u.Thanks

Comment: @imrankhan: Yes, I got that. I just wanted to know the advantages/disadvantages of noth the methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly redesign your project to work with only `AsyncTask`s rather than a `Runnable`.  I'm not sure how `AsyncTask` likes this behavior as well, but I have changed some UI stuff in AsyncTasks before.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private Runnable updateImages= new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        .........
        .........
        ......... 

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               call your asynctask here
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: But it's not on the main thread. Has this worked for you? This is against what the documentation says.